# What is the explanation of the event mentioned in Surat al-Baqarah verse 67-71?

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-baqarah, quranic-events

I think that sometime, somewhere I heard that Muslims should avoid asking so many details about faith and going deep in analyzing haram and halal. Arguments for this is mentioned in Surat al-Baqarah verse 67-71 (the verses which tells the story of slaughtering a cow) :

> 67    And (remember) when Musa (Moses) said to his people: "Verily, Allah
>   commands you that you slaughter a cow." They said, "Do you make fun of
>   us?" He said, "I take Allah's Refuge from being among Al-Jahilun (the
>   ignorant or the foolish)."
>
> 68    They said, "Call upon your Lord for us that He may make plain to us
>   what it is!" He said, "He says, 'Verily, it is a cow neither too old
>   nor too young, but (it is) between the two conditions', so do what you
>   are commanded."
>
> 69    They said, "Call upon your Lord for us to make plain to us its
>   colour." He said, "He says, 'It is a yellow cow, bright in its colour,
>   pleasing to the beholders.' "
>
> 70    They said, "Call upon your Lord for us to make plain to us what it
>   is. Verily, to us all cows are alike. And surely, if Allah wills, we
>   will be guided."
>
> 71    He [Musa (Moses)] said, "He says, 'It is a cow neither trained to
>   till the soil nor water the fields, sound, having no other colour
>   except bright yellow.' " They said, "Now you have brought the truth."
>   So they slaughtered it though they were near to not doing it.

Another arguments for avoid going in details and too much analyzing so deep is this hadith:

**"Haram is clear, Halal is clear other thinks is Allah's mercy"**

I really do not know if this is the right argument, and does this hadith exist at all?
So, I will love to hear the opinions of those who know more than me. Also, if this is the right view it could be the answer to many questions asked here.

Comment: You're mixing up two stories here. There's the story of Banu Israeel sacrificing the cow, and there's the story of the killer and the cow meat. Which exactly are you asking about?

Comment: @ashes999 I referring to Sura Al-Baqara ayah 68,69,70,71. My English i s terrible sory for that

Comment: It is hard to tell what you're asking here.  Are you asking for tafsir explaining the story of the cow, or are you asking about the general discouragement against asking too many questions in matters of religion?  They may be related, but they are two very distinct questions.

Comment: I am asking  general discouragement against asking too many questions in matters of religion?

Comment: instead of CV we should improve this post.

Answer (score 1):

For the 1st story, Allah ask them to find a cow and he didn't specified anything about the attributes of this cow, so they do and get in more details, and that means nothing but complexing things for them. because if they were abide by the first guide of killing a cow so in this case any cow will be fine. so asking so many details will get you in more complexity so that it.
 and Allahu aalam.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to islam.SE - please take a look at the FAQ before getting started asking or answering questions. Also please take a look at highly upvoted questions and answers to get an idea of the quality we expect on this website. If you have any questions you're welcome to join us in the chatroom.