# What a woman should do if she wants to leave a job?

Tags: women, fatwa

I am a teacher. I am doing job from last 14 years. I have three children. Now I want to quit job as I cannot give sufficient time to my children and my home. My husband is not doing any  job continuously. He has switched several jobs. He lost his job mostly within a year from the last few years and the reason is mainly due to the conflict with either some other employee or management. This condition put me in lot of stress as my opinion is that man should bear the pressures and should earn money to run a family. What a woman should do according to the teachings of Islam in such condition?

Comment: Q.S.Durrani this is a very complicated family situation, I think a better solution will be from a scholar/imam in your local mosque, inshaAllah. Would you able to do that or you have no access for it? Plz reply so we can see how to help you with it, inshaAllah.

Comment: To the question i think this link is good enough to understand whether Muslim womens can work or not http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/476/are-women-allowed-to-work-in-islam, but as in your situation where there is a financial problem due unstable job situation of your husband, i think it is a suggestion / advice kind of a thing whether you should continue your job or not. In terms of my suggestion is would suggest you to leave the job and leave rest to allah, Insha Allah all will be well.

Comment: @SamM This is not the nature of Islam. Leaving to Allah without motion is out of Islam. Tawakkul should be with work and strive.

Comment: If you are asking that can women job or not in Islam. Then the answer is  **yes** but with certain conditions like hijab etcetera.

Answer (score -1):

Asalam u Alaikum,

This is totally my **personal** opinion.

1. Your husband should be educated through religion in a nice and humble way how to reduce and leave conflicting with people. He can consult to a medical expert or a sofi saint in your area like Imam of local mosque.
2. He should then start a job.
3. Until then don't leave your job because starvation is much worse than the current condition  if you leave your job right now.
4. Try to get some time management skills to extract sometime to do household work or get a maid if you can afford.
5. Give your children 10 minutes a day, teaching them good things and refreshing their minds with manner teaching Hadiths and stories. This would be enough for them.
6. Lastly and most logical, pray to Allah.

Hope this helps my sister.